# Annual unconditional sharpe ratio vs expected unconditional sharpe ratio

Tags: refinance

What is the difference between the annual (unconditional) Sharpe ratio of a portfolio whose weights are equal to the predicted returns and expected (unconditional) Sharpe ratio of portfolios.

I understand the first part but I struggle to see how the second part differs from the first one.

Comment: I'm guessing that "expected" SR uses _expected_ returns and volatility, while the annual SR uses _historical_ returns and volatility, but it's not clear without more context.